# Get attachment with element ID from list

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get attachment list with element ID from a sharepoint list.
I found script to download attachment but I want to see how you would do it?

Thanks by advance,

++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem :

```
$webUrl = "http://site.fr/"    
$library = "librarieName"
$spSite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webUrl)
$w = $spSite.OpenWeb()
$l = $w.Lists[$library]
$resultHashtable = @{}

foreach ($listItem in $l.Items)
{

    Write-Host "    Content: " $listItem.ID 
    foreach ($attachment in $listItem.Attachments)
    {
        $file = $w.GetFile($listItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $attachment)
        $linkAttachment = $webUrl + $file.ServerRelativeUrl
        $resultHashtable.Add($listItem.ID, $linkAttachment)

    }

}
#Export CSV
$resultHashtable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending |
Select-Object -Property @{n='SiteURL';e={$_.Name}},Value |
Export-Csv -Path Attachments.csv -NoTypeInformation
```